# Monospaced font in Manjaro

Tags: fonts, manjaro, fixed-width, qt5

I have been a user of KeePassXC for pwd-management for a while not and am quite happy with that. When I started using Manjaro with xfce I have not been able to use the monospaced font in notes of KeePassXC entries. I have been trying to solve this issue for a while ([forum post](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/keepassxc-monospaced-font-for-notes-not-applied-in-manjaro/149889)) but with no luck.

Then after a post to the devs of KeePassXC at GitHub, I looked deeper into system settings in Manjaro, specifically QT since that seem to be a source of many UX issues for KeePassXC. And sure enough in

QT5 Configuration tool (QT5 Settings v1.1) > Fonts

it is possible to choose fonts for "General" and "Fixed width". For me this was set to the same font "Cantarell 10". When I set the Fixed width to a *-mono font, I finally got the monospaced font in notes in KeePassXC.

My question is if this is correct that there is by default no differentiation between General and Fixed width font? I.e. is this a possible bug in Manjaro?

Since there is a differentiation in the settings themselves (i.e. General and Fixed width), it seems not logical to have the options set to the same value/same font.

How does it look on your end?

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.60-2-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.0 
           Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 tk: Gtk 3.24.20 info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm4 
           dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Manjaro Linux
```

Comment: Manjaro is just a collection of Linux programs, images, fonts and default configurations... generally QT5 works the same on all platforms - but things like Snap and Appimages adds another layer of customization that's not always in sync with the OS, so I think it's important to mention how you installed it. That said, I apt-installed it in Ubuntu and nothing is monospace and there are no settings to make it. Yes there's a regular/mono distinction, but it needs to be part the code, you'll likely have to change it in the code and compile it for yourself... or add a setting and do a pull request.

Comment: So no, not a bug in Majaro.. but something not catered for in KeePassXC. You might be able to find a Qt configuration utility to set all the fonts to mono, or delete the font it uses, and it might fall back to a monospaced one... if it was ever monospaced for you that was probably the issue: the actual font referenced was not available, and neither were any other variable fonts.